# Cropping an image with an outline

Tags: java, android, android-image

I have a captured image, the image consists of a table. I want to crop the table out of that image.
[This is a sample image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQepo.jpg)
Can someone suggest what can be done?
I have to use it in android.

Comment: Do your images have the red dots?

Comment: Will table always be completely surrounded by pure white?

Comment: Is perspective transform needed?  Are the images from a camera? scanner?

Comment: no the image don't have the red dots, the image will always be surrounded by pure white and the image is from a camera.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hough transform to find the lines in the image.

OpenCV can easily do this and has java bindings.   See the tutorial on this page on how to do something very similar.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html

Here is the java code provided in the tutorial:

```
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.highgui.HighGui;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
class HoughLinesRun {
    public void run(String[] args) {
        // Declare the output variables
        Mat dst = new Mat(), cdst = new Mat(), cdstP;
        String default_file = "../../../../data/sudoku.png";
        String filename = ((args.length > 0) ? args[0] : default_file);
        // Load an image
        Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread(filename, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        // Check if image is loaded fine
        if( src.empty() ) {
            System.out.println("Error opening image!");
            System.out.println("Program Arguments: [image_name -- default "
                    + default_file +"] \n");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        // Edge detection
        Imgproc.Canny(src, dst, 50, 200, 3, false);
        // Copy edges to the images that will display the results in BGR
        Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, cdst, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
        cdstP = cdst.clone();
        // Standard Hough Line Transform
        Mat lines = new Mat(); // will hold the results of the detection
        Imgproc.HoughLines(dst, lines, 1, Math.PI/180, 150); // runs the actual detection
        // Draw the lines
        for (int x = 0; x < lines.rows(); x++) {
            double rho = lines.get(x, 0)[0],
                    theta = lines.get(x, 0)[1];
            double a = Math.cos(theta), b = Math.sin(theta);
            double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
            Point pt1 = new Point(Math.round(x0 + 1000*(-b)), Math.round(y0 + 1000*(a)));
            Point pt2 = new Point(Math.round(x0 - 1000*(-b)), Math.round(y0 - 1000*(a)));
            Imgproc.line(cdst, pt1, pt2, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, Imgproc.LINE_AA, 0);
        }
        // Probabilistic Line Transform
        Mat linesP = new Mat(); // will hold the results of the detection
        Imgproc.HoughLinesP(dst, linesP, 1, Math.PI/180, 50, 50, 10); // runs the actual detection
        // Draw the lines
        for (int x = 0; x < linesP.rows(); x++) {
            double[] l = linesP.get(x, 0);
            Imgproc.line(cdstP, new Point(l[0], l[1]), new Point(l[2], l[3]), new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, Imgproc.LINE_AA, 0);
        }
        // Show results
        HighGui.imshow("Source", src);
        HighGui.imshow("Detected Lines (in red) - Standard Hough Line Transform", cdst);
        HighGui.imshow("Detected Lines (in red) - Probabilistic Line Transform", cdstP);
        // Wait and Exit
        HighGui.waitKey();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
public class HoughLines {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Load the native library.
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        new HoughLinesRun().run(args);
    }
}
```

Lines or LinesP will contain the found lines.  Instead of drawing them (as in the example) you will want to manipulate them a little further.

Sort the found lines by slope.

The two largest clusters will be horizontal lines and then vertical lines.
For the horizontal lines calculate and sort by the y intercept.
The largest y intercept describes the top of the table.
The smallest y intercept is the bottom of the table.

For the vertical lines calculate and sort by the x intercept.
The largest x intercept is the right side of the table.
The smallest x intercept is the left side of the table.

You'll now have the coordinates of the four table corners and can do standard image manipulation to crop/rotate etc.  OpenCV can help you will this step too.

Comment: Hough transform is not needed - if he has the red dots!!

Comment: Can you help me with to sort with x intercept and y intercept?

Comment: Do you not know how to calculate the intercepts or how to sort?  What have you tried?  Would you also like me to write the Android app for you?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your image to grayscale.

Threshold your image to drop noise.

Find the minimum area rect of the non-blank pixels.

In python the code would look like:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('table.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 222, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )
# write out the thresholded image to debug the 222 value    
cv2.imwrite("thresh.png", thresh)

indices = np.where(thresh != 255)
coords = np.array([(b,a) for a, b in zip(*(indices[0], indices[1]))])
# coords = cv2.convexHull(coords)
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(coords) 
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(img, [box], 0, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imwrite("box.png", img)
```

For me this produces the following image. 
[image]

If your image didn't have the red squares it would be a tighter fit.

Comment: its showing error as:
File "e.py", line 6, in <module>
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Depending on your version of opencv findContours may return three items.  But you really don't even need to do findContours if your image is fairly clean.  I'll update the example.

Comment: when i used this for another captured image, instead of covering the box it's covering the whole image.

Comment: This method is highly dependent on the input image being relatively "clean" and the threshold parameter (222) being appropriate.

Comment: What does your new image look like?  You can try writing thresh to an image and visually inspect.  Try adjusting the 222 value.

Comment: You may need to do some work to clean up your input images.  Filter by color, erode/dialate, perform a blur.